# Mailitem closed in VBA is still locked (can't be reopened)

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some code (can't share it in full) that runs just fine for most users.

For one user on Windows 10, when the code opens a .msg file and later closes the file and sets olMail to Nothing, the underlying .msg file in the folder is still locked as if it's open (get error message indicating the file is already open). This doesn't happen for others, but consistently happens for this user.

Sample code:

```vb
sub checkMail()
    '' standard code above to initiate outlook, etc

    set olMail = Session.openshareditem(filepath & filename)

    ''code checks a bunch of stuff, stores some info about the email

    olMail.close 0
    set olMail = Nothing

    ''later on in the code, after looping through all the emails, we come back to specific 
    ''ones that have been identified

    set olMail = Session.openshareditem(filepath & filename) '''THIS STEP FAILS TO OPEN

    ''and so on...
```

Comment: Would `olMail.close 1` olDiscard be sufficient? This may have an impact.

Comment: If not successful [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since you are initiating Outlook from another application you could tag the question with that other application.

Comment: Why do you open the same item twice in the same sub? Isn't it better to keep the reference until the end of sub and then release it.

Comment: what does `code checks a bunch of stuff` do? Do you access attachments and/or recipients?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to close the item if you need it in the same VBA function. So, I'd suggest keeping the reference until the end of function/sub in VBA. Otherwise, you need to limit the scope of references and set them to null in the end of scope, so references will be cleaned up. But it is up to the VBA runtime when to release such references.